# Save CSV content into mysql database using groovy

Tags: mysql, database, csv, groovy

I'm trying to save csv file data into my mysql database table using groovy language.
I'm new to this language, can anyone please help me in this??
below is piece of code I have written yet.

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

def sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/csvdb",
  "root", "", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
def users = sql.dataSet("USERS")
new File("C:\Users\lllha\Desktop\users.csv").splitEachLine(",") {fields ->
 users.add(
    first_name: fields[0],
    last_name: fields[1],
    age: field[2],
    gender: field[3],
    email: fields[4],
    phone: fields[5]
  )
}
```

Comment: Upload CSV to MySQL server if it is not local for MySQL now, then use LOAD DATA query. Transferring the data via the client is not reasonable in most cases.

Comment: What is your question?  How does your code fail? Please add an actual problem statement.

Comment: Look at this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36884925/3355860